# what are the environmental variables needed for tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, environment-variables

I am trying to deploy tomcat from command prompt using startup.bat
But while running, the tomcat window closes immediately.
I have set system environment variables

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
```

what else should i do to deploy????

Comment: does it print something in the log?

Comment: are you set system environment variables for tomcat?

Comment: No. it dies with in 1 second

Comment: If you don't see any errors in the console, try looking in the `logs` folder.

Comment: No files are there in logs folder. what environmental variable needed to tomcat?

Comment: What is your question? tomcat not starting or you can not deploy?

Comment: both are not happening.. when i try to put localhost:8080,it shows tomcat page. but not from command prompt i cant start and deploy the tomcat.what i need to give to start tomcat from command prompt?

Comment: what do you mean by dies? did you try accessing the server through a browser http://localhost:8080

Comment: dies in the sense it closes immediately after tomcat window opens. If i open through browser localhost:8080 it works.

Comment: `PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin` is dangerous, because **no** other program will be found. You need to have at least `c:\Windows` and `c:\Windows\system32`. Use `PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;%PATH%` instead

Comment: " If i open through browser localhost:8080 it works" yeah so it doesn't die, its running. Tomcat doesn't have a window at all, what you are probably describing is the command prompt closing after you double click the startup script.

Comment: no command prompt doesnot show error .only tomcat console window is closing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the environment variable for Tomcat? If not, set `CATALINA_HOME` user variable and set it to  your tomcat directory e.g. `D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63`
And then add that variable to Path as `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin`